# The angular datepicker totally mis-behavior as expectation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, momentjs

I ran into a deadly chaos on datepicker issues.

Who can solve my problem I can give 100 point as a return.

When I click the calendar on 2016-08-23 it will show me the 2016-08-22 as the date value.

Furthermore, the date value in angular model is also not correct.

I want to make the output can be consistent.

To reproduce the buggy issue, change your timezone between LA and TOKYO

[image: inline]

DEMO site: https://test.jiyubi.com/tour_package/home

[image: inline]

## controller js

```
app.controller('tourPackageStartDatePickerCtrl',
    function ($scope) {

        $scope.initStartDate = function () {
           $scope.startDate = $scope.startDate || null;
        };
        $scope.initStartDate();


        $scope.dateOptions = {
            baseDate: $scope.startDate,
            minDate: $scope.startDate || moment.utc().toDate(),
        };

        $scope.openStartDateClick = function () {
            $scope.startDatePopup.opened = true;
        };


    });

app.controller('tourPackageEndDatePickerCtrl',
    function ($scope, $rootScope) {

        $scope.clear = function () {
            $scope.endDate = null;
        };

        $scope.endDateOptions = {
            dateDisabled: disabledDays,
            baseDate: new Date(),
        };

        $scope.openEndDateClick = function () {
            $scope.endDatePopup.opened = true;
        };


        $scope.$watch("endDate", function (new_val, old_val) {
            if (new_val && moment(new_val).isValid()) {
                setTravelDateRange($scope.startDate, $scope.endDate);
            }
        }, true)

        function setTravelDateRange(startDate, endDate) {
            var start_date = moment_with_TAIPEI_TZ(startDate).format("YYYY/MM/DD");
            var end_date = moment_with_TAIPEI_TZ(endDate).format("YYYY/MM/DD");
            moment(startDate.toDateString()).tz("Asia/Taipei").format("YYYY/MM/DD");
            $scope.q_param.startDate = start_date;
            $scope.q_param.date_range = start_date + "-" + end_date;
        }


    });
```

## helper.js

```
    function moment_with_TAIPEI_TZ(time){
       return moment(time).tz("Asia/Taipei");
    }

    function MOMENT_WITH_LOCAL(time){
       return moment(time).local();
    }

    function discard_timezone(value) {
       return moment.utc(value).format(DEFAULT_MOMENT_TIME_FORMAT);
    }

    function getYYYYMMDD(value) {
       return moment.utc(value).format("YYYY/MM/DD");
    }

    function date_without_timezone(value) {
       return moment.utc(value).toDate();
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps it is issue in `moment` not in `datepicker`.

Comment: Sounds like a time zone issue, LA is UTC-0800, Tokyo is currently UTC+0900 so up to 17:00 in Tokyo it is the previous day in LA.

Comment: it's not supposed to have this strange issue happen, right? this is totally a buggy output, although it might related to the timezone :(

Answer (score 0):

It's may be because of a timezone issue.
Could you please try to convert to date without considering the timezone?

```js
this.convertToDateWithoutTimezone = function(date) {
    if (date.toString().match(/(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)/)) {
        var year = $filter('date')(date.slice(0, 10), 'yyyy'),
            month = $filter('date')(date.slice(0, 10), 'MM'),
            day = $filter('date')(date.slice(0, 10), 'dd');
        return new Date(year, month - 1, day);
    } else {
        return new Date(date);
    }
};
```

Comment: I will try your solution later, thanks for your support :D

Comment: What is the date format of the input? And what you getting aftr conversion?